# Suppose that $(z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $z$. Show that $\overline{z}_{n}\to\overline{z}$ and $|z_{n}|\to |z|$ as $n\to\infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Suppose that $(z_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $\textbf{C}$ which converges to $z$. Show that $\overline{z}_{n}\to\overline{z}$ and $|z_{n}|\to |z|$ as $n\to\infty$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there is a natural number $n_{0}\geq 1$ s.t. $|z_{n} - z|  < \varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq n_{0}$.

Moreover, one has that $|z_{n} - z| = |\overline{z_{n} - z}| = |\overline{z}_{n} - \overline{z}| < \varepsilon$. Thus we conclude that $\overline{z}_{n}\to \overline{z}$ as $n\to \infty$.

Similarly, one has that $||z_{n}| - |z|| \leq |z_{n} - z| < \varepsilon$. Thus $|z_{n}|\to|z|$ as $n\to\infty$, and we are done.

Could someone please check if the wording of my proof is good enough? Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: It  is Ok, but there is a misprint in the 5th line of the proof.

Comment: I have edited it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. By the way, for the second part it suffices to note that $\lvert \:\cdot\:\rvert:\Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous, so that it commutes with limits and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert z_n\rvert=\lvert \lim_{n\to\infty} z_n\rvert=\lvert z\rvert$.

Comment: The question is essentially asking one to prove the continuity of both functions $\bar{\cdot}$ and $|\cdot|$